# Get the odata query parameter in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, odata

I have a below query of select filter in odata.

```
localhost:1034/odata/Pharmacy?$select=MemberAge,ClaimNumber
```

I want to access the `MemberAge` and `ClaimNumber` parameter in `c#` without `split function`.

How can I access the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to say is that if you use the WebAPI OData libraries and return an `IQueryable`, then you don't need to access the select values as the library deals with all of that.

If you really do need to parse this separately to that, then the `ODataQueryOptions` class in the `System.Web.OData.Query` namespace is what parses it within the library and you can use that.

If you aren't using the library at all - and I would strongly advise against that - then you are on your own and you will have to split it yourself.